# Program doesn't recognise global variable in Perl

Tags: perl

```
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::LinkExtor;

$user = 'a***.***'; # Enter your username here
$pass = '***733 '; # Enter your password here
$home = "http://37.48.90.31";
$URL = get("$home/c/test.cgi?u=$user&p=$pass");
$LinkExtor = HTML::LinkExtor->new(\&links);
$LinkExtor->parse($URL);
$imge="";
sub links
  {
    ($tag,%links)= @_;
     if ($tag eq "img") {
        foreach $key (keys %links) {
          if ($key eq "src") 
          {
          $imge = "$links{$key}\n";

          }

    }

    }

}

print  $imge;
```

It doesn't print anything why?

According to what I understood of Perl it should know `$imge` even though it is in a function.

I am new to Perl so I would be glad if someone can tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and use at least `use strict` and even better `use warnings`. These help you to better detect problems yourself. And proper indentation helps too. Also, you set `$imge` to `""` after you called the LinkExtor and this way you delete anything which was in `$imge` before you print the variable.

Answer (score 4):

You are setting `$imge` to a null string after you call `$LinkExtor->parse($URL)`.

Please take note of these points

- You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings`, and declare all of your variables with `my` as close as possible to their first point of use
- Indent your code properly, especially when asking for help with it. It will help you to see the structure better in your own programs, and it is a simple matter of courtesy to present something half readable if you ask for assistance
- Perl variable names should contain only *lower-case* letters, numbers, or underscores. Capitals are reserved for global identifiers like package names
- You are missing the point of hashes. There is no need to search through a hash's keys — you can access a hash element directly in the same way as you can access an array element , so you inner `foreach` loop should be just `$imge = "$links{src}\n"`
- I assume you want to print every `<img>` elemen't `src` atttribute, so you should *append* the value of the attribute to `$imge`. As it stands you are just replacing the value each time you find a new one, so only the *last* value will be printed

This refactoring should work for you, although I haven't been able to test it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::LinkExtor;

my $user = 'a***.***';
my $pass = '***733 ';
my $home = 'http://37.48.90.31';
my $url  = get("$home/c/test.cgi?u=$user&p=$pass");

my $link_extor = HTML::LinkExtor->new(\&links);

my $imge;
$link_extor->parse($url);
print $imge;

sub links {
  my ($tag, %links) = @_;
  $imge .= "$links{src}\n" if $tag eq 'img' and exists $links{src};
}
```